# How to see current memory usage in JVM during a loop?

Tags: java, jvm, jython

I am running a loop in Jython and have a loop of 100K elements which fills up dictionary slowly and eventually crash the app with error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I can track how many elements were processed with a print out to terminal of a current index every 10K elements.

How to print current memory when running app in Jython ?

Want to create output similar to this:

```
10k - 50MB used so far.  
20k - 100MB used so far. 
30k - 150MB used so far. 
...
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how much memory each element consumes?

Comment: No. But would like to know how much 10k consumes. I also want to know how much memory it is consumed by application (not by me raw counting bytes in e.g. string and multiplying with 100K).

Comment: @Scary Wombat - I asked for memory usage via Jython commands - you marked as 'duplicate' question but for Java.. Not sure if you know the difference..

Comment: Sorry Joe - I can't read

Comment: No problem - I added more explanation as well...